# Errrors, when configuring react-native project (building gradle) with android studio. I want to build gradle scripts for using firebase with my app

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I ran into this problem after i updated android studio and the gradle version. Here's what i did step by step:

First i got the following error:

> Build Gradle Error Could not get unknown property 'compile'

I checked stackoverflow and it said that changing "compile" with  "implementation" would solve the problem, and so i did that.

Another issue was that maven was deprecated. So i used, maven-publish instead of maven.

Now i am getting the following error:

> 12:24 PM  Gradle sync failed: Could not find method uploadArchives() for arguments [build_a5ye7ixpcm9qfmol93kt3ucl1$_run_closure4@73b8042a] on project ':expo-application' of type org.gradle.api.Project. (17 s 537 ms)

In this part of code in build.gradle(:expo-application):

```
uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      configuration = configurations.deployerJars
      repository(url: mavenLocal().url)
    }
  }
}
```

I am not really familiar with android studio or java. I just use Android Studio for configuring react native apps for android. Can someone please help me resolve these issues..

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of [Gradle 7.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation), `compile` has been removed in favor of `api`.  When you changed `compile` to `implementation`, you effected the transitive properties of the libraries.  I'm not sure where you read that changing `compile` to `implementation` was the correct answer, but it isn't.  `api` is a much closer approximation to compile.  [This chart](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) gives a fairly easy to understand explanation of why this is.  You should change the `implementation` to `api` and make sure you are using the `java-library` plugin instead of the `java` plugin.  This should allow gradle to see the `UploadArchives` method.  However, this wil cause a new issue.

As of Gradle 6.0, `UploadArchives` is [also deprecated](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#changes_6.0)  along with the `maven` plugin.  You should consider using the `maven-publish` plugin instead.  This will ensure your build continues to work in future Gradle releases.

So, to summarize, make sure your plugins look like this

```
  apply plugin: 'java-library'
  apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

and update your code to use `publishing` instead of `UploadArchives`.  More information on this can be found in the current Gradle user guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/publishing_setup.html).

Alternatively, you can downgrade your gradle version to something before 7.0 and just ignore all the deprecation warnings.  The choice is yours.